# Correct way to handle anonymous and registered users

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am developing an a game application and is debating which is the correct way to handle which user is the owner of a played game.

You can either play as an anonymous guest who only has to provide your location or as a registered user. All users are stored in the database. Once you complete a game a database entry is added with you score and I also want to log who played the game.

The table looks as follows:

USERS ( id | user_name | password | country )
GAMES ( id | user_id | score )

As of now I just store a reference to USERS(id) in GAMES(user_id), how should I handle anonymous users though?

One way is to store every anonymous user as just an id and location and then add a column to GAMES called anonymous_id. But then one of user_id or anonymous_id would have to be NULL for every game depending on if the player was registered or not.

Another way would be to just add all the anonymous users to the USER table and allow user_name and password to be null.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do you store "Country" data somewhere or is it just plain text ?

Comment: Yes, countries are stored in another table which is referenced by USERS (country)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store your Countries elsewhere, I would not add an occurence in the User table for each anonymous user. Because for each anonymous User, you'd have 2 inserted rows (1 in User, 1 in Games).

Instead you could have

```
GAMES ( id | user_id | score | country_id)
```

user_id and country_id would both be nullable foreign keys.

When a registered user ends a game, you store the user_id. You can leave the country_id null because it would be a case of duplicate data. 
When an anonyomous user ends a game, you just store the score and the country_id in Games.

You could identify anonymous users by filtering `user_id is null` in Games, and still have the possibility to have a ranking by user, and by country.